# IntelliSense based snippet handling with Visual Studio 2010 SDK MEF Based text editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mef, vsx, visual-studio-sdk

Using the new Visual Studio 2010 SDK developing against the [MEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensibility_Framework) based editor structure there's a question:

How can I use the MEF editor interfaces to handle snippet behavior in IntelliSense? The `ICompletionSession` itself is not a problem (e.g. get the available snippets) rather filling the snippet, handling the subsequently expected actions like tab, enter behavior, text replacement, etc.

Is there any way to do that without a language service? Checking the built-in behavior in Visual Studio base editor implementation they built the MEF interfaces on top of a set of language service based objects.